# default timeout handler for expect script

Tags: expect

I have a expect script that need to fail when certain any of the expect condition is not meet. For example:

```
expect "Hello World"
```

If the expect script does not find "Hello World" in certain amount of time, it should fail. According to expect manual, I can add a condition `timeout` in the expect, but I have many `expect` statements in the script and I don't want to add a timeout for all of them. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
expect_after {
    timeout {
        puts "a default timeout clause for all subsequent expect commands"
    }
}
```

Subsequent expect commands can still provide their own `timeout` clauses that will take precedence over the above.